# Unable to run Test file using dockerFile only Before and After Suites are executed Before, After and Test Methods functions are not getting invoked

Tags: java, docker, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, testng

**DockerFile**

`FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim`

`WORKDIR /usr/share/tag`

`ADD  target/selenium-docker.jar selenium-docker.jar`

`ADD  target/selenium-docker-tests.jar selenium-docker-tests.jar`

`ADD  target/libs libs`

`ADD src/test/resources/TestSuite/dev_env/testng.xml testng.xml`

`ENTRYPOINT java -cp selenium-docker.jar:selenium-docker-tests.jar:libs/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`

**testng.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <parameter name="env" value="dev_env"/>
    <parameter name="system" value="local"/>
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.testlisteners.TestListeners"/>       
    </listeners>
    <test name="FireFoxTests">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
        <classes>
            <class
                    name="com.tests.HomePageTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name= "testMultiSelectDropdown"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="ChromeTests">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.tests.HomePageTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name= "testMultiSelectDropdown"/>
                </methods>
           </class>           
       </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**BaseTest**

```
@BeforeSuite
    @Parameters({"env", "system"})
    public void preSetup(String env, String system) throws IOException {
        this.env = env;
        this.system = system;
        logger.info("Before Suite is called...");
        oneInstance.add(KEYS.ENVIRONMENT, env);
        oneInstance.add(KEYS.SYSTEM, system);
    }



@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    @Parameters({"browser"})
    public void setup(String browser, Method method) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Before Method is called..");
        String toLowercaseBrowser = browser.toLowerCase();
        this.browser = toLowercaseBrowser;
        logger.info(toLowercaseBrowser + " browser will be launched.");
        ExtentTestManager.startTest(method.getName(), method.getName() + " - " + browser.toUpperCase());

        if (oneInstance.getAsString(KEYS.SYSTEM.name()).equalsIgnoreCase("local")) {
            switch (toLowercaseBrowser) {
                case "chrome":
                    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                    driver.set(new ChromeDriver(setChromeOptions()));
                    getDriver().manage().window().fullscreen();
                    getDriver().get(setAppURL());
                    break;
                case "firefox":
                    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                    driver.set(new FirefoxDriver());
                    getDriver().manage().window().fullscreen();
                    getDriver().get(setAppURL());
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException("browser : " + browser + " is invalid.");
            }
        } else {
                instantiateRemoteWebDriver(toLowercaseBrowser);
                getDriver().manage().window().fullscreen();
                getDriver().get(setAppURL());
        }

    }
```

**I have all my dependencies copied in libs package using maven and also I have verified all my compiled classes for main and test are present in selenium-docker.jar and selenium-docker-tests.jar**

Command I ran for creating selenium-docker.jar and selenium-docker-tests.jar:
`mvn clean package -DskipTests`

Command I used for creating Docker image:
`docker build -t selenium_docker:1.0 .`

Command for running test:
`docker run selenium_docker:1.0`

**Output**

> [DEBUG] 2020-01-24 16:50:48.989 [main] OneInstance - OneInstance is
>   null intialize it....
>
> [INFO ] 2020-01-24 16:50:49.123 [main] BaseTest - Before Suite is
>   called...
>
> [INFO ] 2020-01-24 16:50:49.129 [TestNG-tests-2] TestListeners - I am
>   in onStart method ChromeTests
>
> [INFO ] 2020-01-24 16:50:49.131 [TestNG-tests-1] TestListeners - I am
>   in onStart method FireFoxTests
>
> [INFO ] 2020-01-24 16:50:49.134 [main] BaseTest - Inside driver
>   cleanUp

===============================================
Suite1

## Total tests run: 0, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

In output we can see **Before Suite is called...** but **Before Method is called..** is missing

Comment: I have tried reproducing this issue using TestNG `7.1.0` and I cant reproduce it. I can see `Before Method` being called. Can you please exclude docker from the equation and try reproducing this issue using the latest released version of TestNG (`7.1.0` as of today)

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan thanks for looking into. I was using TestNG ```7.0.0``` and with maven it is working fine. After your suggestion I tried ```7.1.0``` and with maven it is too working fine. **I am facing above issue only when I run myproject with DockerFile** otherwise it is working very smoothly.

Comment: Can you create a simple project on GitHub along with the docker files and share the project link in your question ? Let me see if i can give it a try to see what is going on.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan here is the link of my project [link](https://github.com/racchouhan12/testNG-Selenium-Docker-maven). I have not updated ReadMe. Some info : all XMLs are in test/resources/TestSuite to run project: mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=dev_env/testng.xml. Let me know if more details are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out issue by correcting the file paths in my project. while running locally I have used windows based path but since my test was running in unix system there was exception due to which test was not working after correcting those paths it worked fine. I replaced (\ with /) so it will work in both windows and Unix system.